# :terminal colorscheme inside Vim is different from either Vim or Host Terminal

Tags: vim, terminal, color-scheme, iterm2, hyperterminal

I have a gruvbox theme applied to Vim inside vimrc.
The problem is that when I run the :terminal command inside Vim the colorscheme is different from either the Vim theme or the Terminal theme.
I have tried this on Hyper and iTerm2 and it is the same. Somehow the neither of the colorscheme gets applied to the :terminal. I did try looking at the discussions in github but my knowledge of Vim is not sufficient to understand it. Can someone can explain the problem and the solution? I am running Vim version 8.2.900, Hyper 3.0.2, iTerm 3.3.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:terminal` palette is supposed to be a list named `g:terminal_ansi_colors`, which your colorscheme doesn't define.

You should use their issue tracker to report that oversight and get it fixed… or use a more competently written colorscheme.